# Need help with NOC code for Unix and Production Support duties | Canada Immigration

Tags: immigration, canada

I need help with NOC code, In my present company I work more as application support engineer and also performing SRE responsibilities, **I am confused between 2282/2281/2173/2171**:

My roles and responsibilites are:

• Assist in implementation of SRE(Site reliability engneering) solutions for large scale distributed web applications across multiple tiers
• Provide architectural and practical guidance to software development to improve resiliency, efficiency, performance, and costs
• Perform proactive daily system monitoring including reviewing system and application logs as well as responding to, triaging, troubleshooting and remediating incidents
• Build monitoring tools using Scripting languages like Bash/Python and Java, Develop dashboards using APM tool
• Experience with UNIX/Linux systems administration, network concepts and Database query languages - SQL/NOSQL
• Supported in setting up ELK (ElasticSearch, Logstash, Kibana) platform, parsing unstructured logs using regular expressions to structured JSON format
• Supported in setting up Apache as load balancer for app servers
• Supported in movement of on premise server from DMZ to NDMZ
• Act as top-tier on-call support for critical uptime business applications to maintain availability
and minimize downtime during outage scenarios.
• Work with product operations team to resolve trouble tickets, developing and running scripts,
and troubleshooting services in a hosted environment
• Handle high-pressure situations with a calm and professional manner
• Lead resolution effort of complex service problems from network layer to the application at
scale
• Prioritize between multiple simultaneous issues and projects
• Motivate, encourage, and provide technical leadership to team members

My Skills:

• Good Linux skills and Strong troubleshooting skills
• Good scripting experience with Shell, Python
• Good in Java
• Strong experience in large fleet automation driven by centralized, versioning
configuration/change management via Ansible
• Strong experience of service restoration activities covering web front end, customer facing,
business critical Systems.
• Working knowledge of AWS and good understanding of AWS basics such as EC2, ELB, ALB,
etc. and managed services such as S3, lambda, RDS
• Great in debugging issues and finding RCA.
• Familiarity with Jenkins, CI/CD, and pipelines
• Monitoring - Wily Introscope/AppDynamics
• Setup Apache Tomcat as load balancer, Varnish as caching
• Analysis - GC log Analysis/ Thread Dump Analyzer / Heap Analyzer
• Good knowledge of Networking, TCP/IP, DNS, TLS, Load balancers.
• Good knowledge of SQL query

Comment: Have you read the descriptions?

Comment: did you get any answer. What NOC did you finally use ?

Comment: @ElvisMartinez It's almost a year since the question was posed, and the asker hasn't returned. They probably won't reappear and answer your query.